# Redirect Path is not working even though I am passing all arguments into it

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

I have a post order section of my website and everything is working fine except for the redirect path function. I cannot tell why this function is not working. When I log redirectPath it comes out with the correct path I want from the declaration before but will not redirect the view to the correct path. I also have the redirect path set up so that is not the problem.

```
app.post('/postOrder/:id', async function(req, res, next){
   
  var customerInfo = req.body.info;
  var packageInfo = req.body.items.items;
  var storeID = req.params['id']
  let ts = Date.now();
    let date_ob = new Date(ts);
    let date = date_ob.getDate();
    let month = date_ob.getMonth() + 1;
    let year = date_ob.getFullYear();

let yourOrder = []

packageInfo.forEach((package) => cusOrder(package.product, package.qty));  

function cusOrder(product, qty){
  let order = {product: product, qty: qty}
  yourOrder.push(order);
}
console.log(yourOrder);
  const order = {
      package: yourOrder,
      storenum: storeID,
      date: year+"/"+month+"/"+date,
      first: customerInfo[0].fname,
      last: customerInfo[1].lname,
      address: customerInfo[2].address,
      city: customerInfo[3].city,
      state: customerInfo[4].state,
      zipcode: customerInfo[5].zip
    }
    new Orders(order).save().then(home => {
      res.locals.redirect = "/";
      res.locals.home = home;
      next()
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(`Error updating user by ID: ${error.message}`);
      next(error);
    });
  
},
function(req, res, next) {
  let redirectPath = res.locals.redirect;
  console.log(redirectPath);
  if (redirectPath !== undefined) res.redirect(redirectPath);
  else next();
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either return the promise started by the save function or stick to using async/await instead of the promise directly. I would personally recommend using await

Ex

```
const home = await new Orders(order).save()
```

Comment: Great can you go into a little more detail on what I should do further down in the code?